# Animate objects in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, swift

In swift, I am transitioning an object in to the view, and I need it to slide in, or fade in. How can I obtain this type of animation in my program?

**I have all my view elements made programmatically without IB (Interface Builder)**

Is there documentation I can look at for reference? I could not find any.

Comment: Same way as in Objective C.

Comment: I can't find anything with the type of animation that I want. I just want maybe a simple slide in or fade in. Not an OpenGL game.

Comment: Look up `UIView`'s animate methods. They work the same way in Swift as they did in Obj-C.

Comment: For slide or fade animations you want a `CABasicAnimation` or `CAKeyframeAnimation`, where you set the x/y position or the opacity via the animation. See documentation or other questions showing how to do it in Objective-C, there is plenty of it. If you get stuck, update this question with what you tried to do and a description of what isn't working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apples Core animation seen here https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html
its very fun. youtube it

Comment: Link is broken hence -1

Answer (score 15):

I'm used to using [UIView animateWithDuration ...], but I found it a bit tricky switching the block syntax over to Swift at first. Here's a quick lazy code:

```
view.alpha = 0.0
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
    view.alpha = 1.0
}, completion: {
    (value: Bool) in
    println(">>> Animation done.")
})
```

Comment: can you pls tell me how to animate continously..??

Comment: Perhaps try something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644335/swift-continuous-background-animation-loop

Answer (score 4):

Or to animate the position appearing from the left of the screen:

```
// some variables for the UIView
let width = 200
let height = 100
let yPosition = 10

// create view and position it offscreen to the left    
let view = UIView()

// you could have also used the new more verbose Swift way of making a CGRect:
// CGRect(x: xValue, y: yValue, width: widthValue, height: heightValue)
view.frame = CGRectMake(-width, yPosition, width, height)
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor() // etc...

// animation position over 1.0 second duration
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {

    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, yPosition, width, height)
})
```

If you're completely new to the UIView animation APIs I wrote post that covers a bunch of animation options in swift here: http://mathewsanders.com/prototyping-iOS-iPhone-iPad-animations-in-swift/

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 & 4 
 Please Add necessary objects like tableView

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet var tabl: UITableView!
    var name = ["tony","abu"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return name.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = name[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        tabl.center.x = self.view.frame.width/5

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity:0.45, options: [], animations: ({
            self.tabl.center.x = self.view.frame.width/3
            //self.buttonAction.center.x = self.view.frame.width/2
        }), completion: nil)



    }

}
```